# Microsoft Teams Custom App Anonymous user can't show content Stage View

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

So I want to create a meeting extension App, this app will be able accessed by internal users and anonymous users so we try to deploy this app in our environment https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-anonymous-users/csharp, We are able to deploy it and we can access the app in our internal users. But for our Anonymous users, it will show a message something went wrong whenever we use the stage view.
[image]

We notice there is an update in Microsoft Teams, is this a known bug or issue, we really need this feature.

We already set to for anonymous users can interact with the apps
[image]

And in our manifes.json we already set for support anonymousguestusers too
[image]

Comment: This issue is being tracked here https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/issues/1103. Please check this thread for further updates.